# form not showing for empty records

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I have a relatively simple PHP page called editcustomers with 3 columns. The problem I'm having is that the form will show when there is a record in the database and the fields will be populated with that info.

When no such records exists, the form is not even shown, eliminating the possibility to insert a record.

My page layout is as follows:

- Column 1 shows a form containing customer information, allowing it to
  be edited.
- Column 2 allows ordering of products and showing how many products were ordered
- Column 3 shows the total paid so far, and the total owing.

The code for the page I have at present:

```
<html>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
require_once('connect.php');
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users where id = '$id';");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$eth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM purchases where id = '$id';");
$eth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
    <form name="custInfo" action ="process.php" method ="post" >
    <input type = "hidden" name ="formType" value="custInfo"/>
    <?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){ ?>
    <p><input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" <?php echo $row["firstName"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["lastName"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="country" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["country"]?>"/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <?php }?>
    </div>

    <div id="mid">
   <form name="custCosts" action ="process.php" method ="post" >
   <input type = "hidden" name ="formType" value="custCosts"/>
    <?php while($row = $eth->fetch()){ ?>
    <p><input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="amountOwed" size ="30" value=" <?php echo $row["amountOwed"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="numAaa" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["numAaa"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="numBbb" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["numBbb"]?>"/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <?php }?>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    <b>Total Balance</b>
    <p> Money owed: </p>
    <p> aaa total: </p>
    <p> bbb total: </p>
    <p> Total: </p>
    <input type = "text" name ="pay" size ="20" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Make Payment" />
    </div>
<?php
$dbh =null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code for all the database trickery:

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
$formType = $_POST['formType'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$amountOwed = $_POST['amountOwed '];
$numAaa = $_POST['numAaa'];
$numBbb = $_POST['numBbb'];

if(empty($_POST['id'])) {
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (firstName, lastName, country)
VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$country')");
$sth->execute();

} elseif(!empty($_POST['id']) && !isset($_POST['stayCost']) && $_POST['formType'] == 'guestInfo'){
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE customers SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', country = '$country' WHERE id = '$id'");
$sth->execute();

}elseif(!empty($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['stayCost']) && $_POST['formType'] == 'guestInfo'){
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO purchases (id, amountOwed, numAaa, numBbb)
VALUES ('$id', '$amountOwed', '$numAaa', '$numBbb'");
$sth->execute();

}elseif(!empty($_POST['id']) && $_POST['formType'] == 'guestCosts'){
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE purchases SET amountOwed= '$amountOwed', numAaa = '$numAaa', numBbb= '$numBbb' WHERE id = '$id'");
$sth->execute();
}

$dbh =null;
?>
```

Why does the form not even display if there is no record? An error or something I might understand....but the form is still in the HTML and should still be being output, from what I can see. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $sth->fetch())
```

That means: for each returned row do something. If there's no returned row, nothing included inside the while will execute, so it isn't printing any input!

You should include a if with the rowCount, if this is equal to 0 print inputs so the user can fill them.

```
<?php while($row = $sth->fetch()){ ?>
    <p><input type = "hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=" <?php echo $row["firstName"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["lastName"]?>"/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="country" size ="30" value="<?php echo $row["country"]?>"/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
<?php
   }
   if($sth->rowCount()==0){
 ?>
 <p><input type = "hidden" name ="id" value=""/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="firstName" size ="30" value=""/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="lastName" size ="30" value=""/>
    <p><input type = "text" name ="country" size ="30" value=""/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ahh I feel so stupid for not picking up on that. Could you possibly give an example in your answer, this is my first attempt at programming something, so everything is new to me.

Comment: I edited my answer, something like that `if($sth->rowCount()==0)` should be added either before of after each `while($row = $sth->fetch())`